# Unable to find the error in my code, getting errors with GCC

Tags: c

I'm making a small program that decode and modify a matrix. You can set turns for it. The thing is, I'm getting Stack smashing error on a particular test, and I can't seems to find the error. The error comes at printing the matrix in the output.

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * 
 * @param col
 * @param charM
 * @param row
 */
void printMatrix(char (*charM)[40]) {  
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (a = 0; a < 20; a++){
        for (b = 0; b < 40; b++){
            printf("%c", charM[a][b]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param col
 * @param charM
 * @param row
 */
void readMatrix(char (*charM)[40]) {
    char charT[40] = {0};
    int count = 0;

    while (count < 20) {
        scanf("%s", charT);

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
            charM[count][i] = charT[i];
        }
        count++;
    } 
}  

/**
 * 
 * @param arg
 * @param col
 * @param charM
 * @param row
 */
void pandemicTurns(int arg, char (*charM)[40]){
    int turns = arg;
    int daysCount = 0;

    do {
        if (daysCount == 0) printf("Jour 0\n");
        else printf("Jour %d\n", daysCount);
        printMatrix(charM);
        daysCount++;
        turns--;
    } while (turns != -1);
}


/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     char charM[20][40] = {'0'};

     int argvs = 0;

     if (argc == 1) {
        readMatrix(charM);
        pandemicTurns(0, charM);
     }
     else if(argc == 2 && atoi(argv[1]) > 0 && atoi(argv[1]) <= 100) {
        argvs = atoi(argv[1]);
        readMatrix(charM);
        pandemicTurns(argvs, charM);
     }
     else {
        errorExit(argv);
     }


     return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

When I give this in the input :

(a matrix of 20*40 of '.' char)

```
........................................
```

Everything works. But when I start to mix H and X in it :

```
H.HHH..XX.H......X..HH.......XHX........
```

I get a stack smashing error. It stops at Day 2 and 3rd row of the printing.

Comment: length of `H.HHH..XX.H......X..HH.......XHX........` is **40**. So You need `char charM[20][40]` --> `char charM[20][40+1]`

Comment: Both of them length are 40. Yet one works, the other don't. If I put [20][41], it stack smashes every tests.

Comment: So `char charT[40] = {0};` --> `char charT[40+1] = {0};`

Comment: Still doesn't work. =/

Comment: _Still doesn't work_ is insufficient explanation :D (You are doing the wrong fix. You are making inputs that are not supposed to be taken. Code other than the part presented is a problem. etc.etc.)

Comment: Basically, I'm reading line by line and replacing every char in charM for the input. So far it works. I was debugging it and found that all the rows and columns are filled with the right char. When I printf the matrix, I use 2 for loops. It travels each rows by printing each char in the row, then skip to the next when the index reaches 39 (end of the matrix row, 0-39).

Comment: But with this particular one, it overflow. When compiling everything is going fine. When executing it, it crashes at the second day and row 3, column 21. Every time. I tried multiple config, it doesn't do it with them.

Comment: It is meaningless explanation. Provide  [mcve].

Comment: One thing you should fix right off the bat is your calls to `scanf`.  *Never* use the `scanf` `%s` specifier to read a string.  It does no bounds checking, so if someone enters a string that's even one character longer than what you can hold, you will corrupt your run time environment.

Comment: I fixed the issue using fgets instead. But know I have an issue where I don't know how to read the lines until the end of file. It keeps waiting for a new input, which I want to stop reading after pasting my matrix in the console via stdin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue using fgets() instead of scanf().